# how to overcome font problem in blackberry?

Tags: unicode, blackberry, character-encoding

I am reading data from a .csv file and displaying it. When I encounter the micro character (µ) some special symbols are displayed instead. How can I display the micro character?

Answer (score 2):

```
class Scr extends MainScreen
{
    public Scr() {
        LabelField label = new LabelField();        
        String fontName = label.getFont().getFontFamily().getName();
        String text = "Font name: "+fontName+" Symbol: µ";
        label.setText(text);
        add(label);
    }   
}
```

[screen http://img207.imageshack.us/img207/9606/screenwx.jpg](http://img207.imageshack.us/img207/9606/screenwx.jpg)
Can't reproduce on RIM OS 4.5 Curve 8300, font "BBAlpha Sans".

- Check what font are you using, there may be no "µ" symbol
- Try to debug and see if symbol is readed correctly from file

Comment: Good suggestions.  It's worth noting that the BBAlpha fonts were not added until 4.3 so if you're using 4.2.2 or earlier, you're stuck with really bad looking fonts!